# Shortcuts in the Shortcuts App disappear after being pinned?

Tags: macos, shortcuts-app

I don't know whether this is a bug or whether it's intended behavior and I'm missing something fundamental here, but on Monterey 12.2.1 a ton of my shortcuts have disappeared entirely from the Shortcuts app after having pinned them in the menu bar. They haven't been deleted, rather they're somehow hidden, not being show in `All Shortcuts` or any other folder. The only exception is the `Recently Run` folder. (And since the iPhone doesn't have this folder, there they're completely gone.)

What's odd is that they haven't actually been deleted because creating a shortcut with the same name as one of the ones that vanished will report that a shortcut with this name already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It seems that "Pin in Menu Bar" is implemented via a folder which the Shortcuts app creates behind your back. Pinning a shortcut to the menu bar moves it to this folder behind your back. What's worse, this folder has no name, so the only indication of its presence is the shortcut count shown in light gray at the bottom of the list of folders like this:

[image]

What's worse is that there's a lag between the time that a shortcut is pinned and the time when it disappears from its original folder and reappears in the pinned folder. All this is very confusing and feels pretty shoddy.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to bring the hidden shortcut back. The Shortcuts app comes with an Open Shortcut action that brings you to the editor for the input shortcut. You can create a temporary shortcut to go to the hidden shortcut (it's still available in the input list) and update its setting.

[image: Open Shortcut action]

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Sonoma, it has a name known as "Menu Bar". It also shows up in the Menu Bar, under a shortcut icon. It might be the same in macOS Monterey.
Tip: If it doesn't show up, try removing some things by holding Cmd and then dragging things out.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/343246)